# <html:select> problem with <html:options> tag

Tags: java, struts

I've a form with struts tags as below.

```
<html:form styleId='catform' action='/cat/submit.html' method='post'>
   <html:select property='catName' styleId='catName'>
      <html:options collection='catList' property='category'>
   </html:select>
</html:form>
```

In my action I'm setting catList as below

```
 List <Category> catList = getCategoryList();
   request.setAttribute("catList", catList);
```

here Category is a class with catName and catId as variables.

I'm getting an error which says no getter for the property category found.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put

```
<html:options collection='catList' property='catId' labelProperty='catName'>
```

struts is trying to get the `category` property of the `Category` instance

Comment: What if List is of String ie: List<String> catList = getCategoryList()? Here what should I use?

Comment: well struts calls what you define on the property attribute on each element of the list, if no property is specified it uses the element directly, in your case the actual String

Answer (score 1):

You need to put either a "collection", which is done between java tags like this :

```
collection="<%= myCollection %>"
```

or to use the "name" and "property" attributes like this :

```
name="mybean" property="beanPropertyWhichContainsTheCollection"
```

Don't use both "property" and "collection" attributes.